# Describe the image under $\exp$ of the line with equation $y = x$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Describe the image under $\exp$ of the line with equation $y = x$. Plot it reasonably carefully, and explain what happens in the limits as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

What I did is let $w=x+yi$ is one point in the image. So
$$\log w=\ln|w|+iArg(w)=\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+i \arctan \frac{y}{x}$$
Thus
$$\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \arctan \frac{y}{x}$$
I am not sure whether I did it in the right direction and I don' know how to go further...Any help? Thanks

Comment: I think you did this in the wrong direction. Note that the problem is asking you to describe the image of the line under exponentiation rather than asking your to describe the preimage of the line after exponentiation.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I did...I did not  describe the preimage of the line after exponentiation. @CyclotomicField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\exp(x+xi)=e^x\bigl(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\bigr).$$Therefore, the image of the line $y=x$ is a spiral.